# Sequential hypothesis test for uniform distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, sequential-analysis, combining-p-values

Suppose I have a sequence of data points $x_1,x_2,\dots$.  I want to do a sequential hypothesis test, were the null hypothesis is that each $x_i$ is iid uniform on $[0,1]$, and the alternative hypothesis is that the $x_i$'s are systematically smaller than that.

If I observed all of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and then do a hypothesis test once, one approach is to use Fisher's method: compute $y=-2\sum_i \log_e x_i$, note that $y$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom, and use that to compute a $p$-value.

However, I want to do a *sequential* hypothesis test, where after receiving each $x_n$, I either reject the null hypothesis or ask for the next data point.  (In my situation, I never stop early and accept the null hypothesis; I only stop early if I can reject it.)  I want the chance of Type 1 error (i.e., that I ever reject at any point, if fed data distributed according to the null hypothesis) to be at most $\alpha$.  Is there an appropriate method to use in this situation?

I'm noticing a connection to the literature on combining $p$-values, since this situation also arises when each $x_i$ is a $p$-value; except now I'm looking for a stopping rule that yields a good sequential hypothesis test.

I could imagine a method that uses a Bonferroni-style correction, i.e., a union bound.  For a given $n$, let $y_n=-2\sum_{i=1}^n \log_e x_i$, let $q=2^{1 + \lfloor \lg n \rfloor}$ be the next largest power of two, look up the threshold for a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom at significance level $2\alpha/q^2$, and reject the null hypothesis if $y_n$ is above that threshold.  This ensures that the total risk of Type 1 error is at most $\sum_n 2\alpha/q^2 \approx \alpha$.  However, this is overly conservative, because it uses a Bonferroni-style correction, which assumes that the test statistics $y_1,y_2,\dots$ are independent, when in fact they are correlated.  Is there a better approach?